# Jquery unbind specifichandler rather than all clicks

Tags: jquery, unbind

I have a menu which slide Toggles when max-width is 969px. There's also a function for when a nav link is clicked to close (SlideUp) the menu. I don't what this behaviour when the viewport is > 969px.

This is the jquery I currently have which is working, however I want to find an alternative to unbinding the 'nav li a' click as it disables my ScrollTo script. Is there a way to specifically unbind that previous function rather than all clicks? Can I give it a name?

```
$(window).resize(function(){
if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 969px)').matches)
{
    $("#MenuToggle").unbind( "click" );
    $('#jqmenu').hide()

    $('#MenuToggle').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('cross'),
        $('#jqmenu').slideToggle('slow') 
    });

    $('nav li a').click(function() {
        $('#MenuToggle').toggleClass('cross'),
        $('#jqmenu').slideUp('slow') 

    });

    }

    else{
        $('#jqmenu').show()
        $("nav li a").unbind( "click" );
    }
}).resize();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var foo = function() {
  // Code to handle some kind of event
};
// ... Now foo will be called when paragraphs are clicked 
$( "p" ).bind( "click", foo );

// ... foo will no longer be called. 
$( "p" ).unbind( "click", foo );
```